# What is the schema for MSChart template xml?

Tags: asp.net, charts, mschart

Anyone know where to find the schema for templates used in `System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting`?

Background info:
In object `System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart`, you can load an XML file that serves as a template for your charts. Here would be a VB call to use it. I am putting this in my question so anyone searching can find the answers here.

```
Chart1.LoadTemplate(Template.SelectedItem.Value + ".xml")
```

Link to Microsoft's MSDN article regarding the method: [Chart..::.LoadTemplate Method (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd467340%28VS.100%29.aspx)

Extra bonus: do you use templates? Can you point me to online resources that I should know about specific to templating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not found the actual definition of the template XML. Instead, I set the properties of my chart as I needed it and then saved the properties as a template. Once I had the file then I can modify it to make it more like a real template that can be used by other similar chart objects.

[Microsoft Article on Save](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.chartserializer.save.aspx)